# TeXLive 2017 generates "LaTeX: problems after <n> pages"

Tags: auctex, aquamacs

I just upgraded to TeXLive 2017 as I needed one of the package updates. Now, whenever I process a file, I get the message above (I'm on Mac OS Sierra). It appears that the file processes correctly and that the error message is erroneous. From some searching, it seems that this might be an AUCTeX bug (see for example [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2017-05/msg00022.html).

Now, I use Aquamacs, which ships with AUCTeX preloaded. So I have a few questions that I'm hoping someone can answer:

1. Is this in fact an AUCTeX bug? If not, what?
2. Does the file process correctly even with the error message?
3. Can I safely place a new AUCTeX version on top of the current Aquamacs version (which is in fact the latest Aquamacs version)? If not, does anyone know when or if Aquamacs will be upgraded to use the newer AUCTex?

Comment: 1) Yes, this is a bug in AUCTeX and can be fixed by upgrading the package (version 11.91 was released today).  2) Yes, the file most probably compiled fine  3) I have no idea about how Aquamacs works